# Fancybox error in line code

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm making picasa gallery on my webpage and found some errors in inspect element - console http://my-cravings.com/earth-matters. Then I found this **code** which I cannot find in my index.php. Please help.

Here is the original link http://ahamlett.com/jQuery-Picasa-Gallery/. My problem is I cannot make jquery fancybox work in my webppage.

```
<script>
do_nothing( function() {

});
function do_nothing() { return; }
</script>
```

Comment: Your code is a bit of a mess. You are loading two different versions of jQuery, your scripts are loaded all over the place ( top, bottom, middle of the page) as are you stylesheets and the most important thing is you do not have fancybox loaded on your page so you can never get it to work since it is not there!

Comment: Thanks man.. Now i have a sample fancybox working, I have another question , How will i merge the fancybox with picasa web albums? i want the fancybox effect to be applied in picasa.. Thanks. :) Please help. please check again this link  http://my-cravings.com/earth-matters